# how to add every time a random value to a field in another screen

Tags: flutter

i have a function that give me a random number, and i'm trying to use the value generated to a field in an other screen.
more specific this function is on another class(other file) and i want to call it on other class to add the value generated to other value.
here is my function code.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Can you provide some more code, please. So we can understand what you are trying to do? In general there are multiple ways to pass data from one class to another. I am sure that we can find one, that is suitable for your case.

Comment: `class _RewardsScreenState extends State<RewardsScreen> {
List<int> pointValue = [5,6,7,8,10,15];
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    startTimer();
}
 startTimer() async{
      var duration=Duration(seconds: 4);
      return Timer(duration,route);
    }
    route(){
      Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CardScreen()));
    }
    
 int generateRandomNumber() {
                            return pointValue[new Random().nextInt(pointValue.length)];
      
                            }`

Comment: i want every time when i have a value from this function to add it to another field value to cumulate points it's like i'm doing rewards points. thaaank youu.

Comment: Just edit your question to contain the code

Comment: i edit the question